# Need to make a function to code a word

Tags: c, function

Write a function which as an argument get a char array (a text for coding) . The function needs to code that text.The coding is done like this : The letter a is swapped with the letter z, b with y and etc(The first letter of the alphabet swapped with the last letter of the alphabet , and the second letter of the alphabet swapped example b with y.

Example : abba

Result : zyyz

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int funk(char *alphabet,int i, int n,char *word,int j,int x){
   while(i<n){
      if(word[i]=alphabet[j]){
         word[i]=alphabet[x-i];
         i++;
      }
      else
         j++;
   }

   return word[i];
}

void main ()
{
   int i=0,j=0,n,x;
   char alphabet[]={'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
   char word[10];

   n=strlen(word);
   x=strlen(alphabet);
   printf("Enter your word :\n");

   for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
      scanf("%s",word[i]);
   }

   {
     word=funk(n,azbuka,word,x,i,j);

      for(i=0;i<n;i++){
         printf("%s",word[i]));
      }
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: Please show us your code, what have you tried and explain the problem you are having. You should read the Rules of Stackoverflow.

Comment: ...and how is this post different from your previous one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27693749/c-program-making-a-function-that-codes-a-word? Please take time to review the Help section of this site to make the most of it.

Comment: Need a little help with the code, i posted it in the description.

Comment: @Saite please post the actual code here, not as a screenshot on some other site.

Comment: @Daniel A. White  Its kind of too big ... wont let me post it here..Should i add it in the description ? Sorry im kind of new here , just need some help with the code.

Comment: yes edit your question and post it here.

Comment: Please just post the function rather than the supporting code, and also tell us what output you're getting and how it differs from what you want to get.

Comment: @Saite, it's 36 lines long according to your link. SO won't prevent you from putting that in the question.

Comment: @Dancrumb There it is posted in the descrption , by the way zbor means word and azbuka means alphabet.

Comment: @ Daniel A. White Done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program can be greatly simplified. The logic for the "encode" logic should be just a couple lines of code. Your function declaration/prototype is also exceedingly complicated. Don't forget that a C-string is just a character array terminated with the NULL character (`'\0'`).

**Code Listing**

---

```
/*******************************************************************************
 * Preprocessor directives
 ******************************************************************************/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>


/*******************************************************************************
 * Constants
 ******************************************************************************/
#define MAX_BUF_SIZE

/*******************************************************************************
 * Function Prototypes
 ******************************************************************************/
void encode(char* str, size_t length);


/*******************************************************************************
 * Function Definitions
 ******************************************************************************/
void encode(char* str, size_t length) {
   if (!str || (length <= 1)) {
      return;
   }
   int i;
   for (i=0; i<length; i++) {
      if (isalpha(str[i])) {
         if (isupper(str[i])) {
            str[i] = 'Z' - str[i] + 'A';
         } else {
            str[i] = 'z' - str[i] + 'a';
         }
      }
   }
}

int main(void) {
   char buf1[] = "This is a test";
   char buf2[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
   char buf3[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

   char* inputStrings[] = {buf1, buf2, buf3};
   char* buf;
   int i;

   for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
      buf = inputStrings[i];
      printf("Original String: %s\n", buf);
      encode(buf, strlen(buf));
      printf("Encoded String:  %s\n", buf);
      encode(buf, strlen(buf));
      printf("Decoded String:  %s\n", buf);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

**Sample Run**

---

```
Original String: This is a test
Encoded String:  Gsrh rh z gvhg
Decoded String:  This is a test
Original String: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
Encoded String:  zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba
Decoded String:  abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
Original String: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
Encoded String:  ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
Decoded String:  ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Comment: Nice answer:  Suggest reserving the uppercase "NULL" for the "null pointer" or `NULL` and "null character" for `'\0'`.

Comment: @chux For the sake of consistent style, agreed!

Comment: @Saite Also, this is a simple linear transformation, not too different from the classical ROT13 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13) encoding. You just apply the same transformation to reverse it, like ROT13, normalized fourier transforms, etc.

Comment: @Dogbert Im not that really advanced , but thank you alot . One more question : I dont really understand this line str[i] = 'Z' - str[i] + 'A'; And why are you putting all bufs in one array?

Comment: @Saite A string is just an array of characters that end with `'\0'`. The variable, `buf`, is actually an array of `pointer-to-char`, not an array of `char`. I use it so I can loop through each buffer instead of having to re-type the same code for them. Here's a great article on understanding complex data declarations in c: http://ieng9.ucsd.edu/~cs30x/rt_lt.rule.html

Comment: @Saite And second, the line `str[i] = 'Z' - str[i] + 'A'`, it's another linear transformation. If you look at the ASCII table (http://www.asciitable.com/), you see that each character is actually a number, represented as a single symbol. The 'A'/'a' symbols act as your "offset" (ie: the zero-point). If you want to print the n'th letter of the alphabet, you just calculate, ie: `int n; n=15; char c; c = n + 'a';` So it all boils down to simple character arithmetic.

Comment: #Dogbert Thanks alot Dogbert, i see your logic now ... finally! Too bad they didn't teach this at school , as you can see by my code , they teach us some complicated ways of doing it. By the way it would print out the letter 'p' if i'm not mistaken :P

Comment: @Saite One more thing that should help you: read up on the concept of "base plus offset" for pointers, characters, etc. A lot of low level logic works this way (ie: different ways you can address an array, how `arr`, `&arr[0]` are more or less the same, how `sizeof` doesn't work on function arguments like you think it would, etc. BTW, welcome to StackOverflow!